# How to serve gzip compressed file on production in angular7

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, angular7

```
var BrotliGzipPlugin = require('brotli-gzip-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new BrotliGzipPlugin({
            asset: '[path].br[query]',
            algorithm: 'brotli',
            test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        }),
        new BrotliGzipPlugin({
            asset: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })
    ]
}
```

I am using this code but couldn't able to serve the compressed file on production mode and also using Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough code here to provide a definitive answer, I think ... but here's where I would start looking:  "in the client-side browser logs."  You should see an HTTP request going out, and a GZIP-encoded reply coming back *with the HTTP header tag `Content-Encoding: gzip`.*

Well, *do* you see the request going out?  Was the return-code `200 OK`?  Was the encoding specified?  What did the client-side browser actually do?  Unfortunately you tell us none of these things.

(Also be mindful that many browser exchanges use `gzip` encoding routinely for everything.  The algorithm's so fast that it's basically free ...)